Churchill said that democracy is the worst form of government - except for all the rest. So if democracy is the least worst, how can it be improved?
I was intrigued by a recent question about which forms of government are better or worse. If they are all bad, as Churchill said, but some are better than others, how do we improve his least worst - democracy? Does philosophy provide rational, objective means of doing this?
I am not looking for absolute proof of principle. Just as we can reasonably infer other minds, we can reasonably infer routes to improving democracy.
My interest is practical philosophy.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Lots of great answers and suggestions. Let me add Popper's The Open Society and its Enemies. Consistent with his trial-and-error approach to science, he argues that the main advantage of democracy is the capacity to pull back and learn from mistaken policies, and replace the worse leaders. In summary, democracy is NOT a system where the best get elected, but one where the worst don't get re-elected.
It's similar to his critique of logical positivism: according to Popper, science is NOT a method to arrive at positively true theories, but a method to eliminate false theories. Hence the concept of falsifiability, which he extends to politics in The Open Society.

There have been a number of philosophers of the past starting most famously from Plato who strongly criticised democracy, Aristotle was more measured but still classified democracy amongst the deviant/bad forms. Later Thoreau in the essay Civil Disobedience criticised democracy as a freebie that stifles conscience. This essay gave Gandhi the initial name of the movement that finally succeeded in removing British colonial rule from India.
The following is is in two parts, first a more complete list of past great philosophers critical of democracy.
And then a current list of issues.
JFTR: It is made with about a dozen prompts to chatGPT.
Past Philosophers who were critical of democracy
1. Plato
Plato's criticism of democracy is rooted in his belief that it allows for rule by the ignorant masses rather than by the wise. In his famous work, The Republic, he presents democracy as the second-worst form of government (just above tyranny). He argues that democracy prioritizes freedom and equality to the extent that it leads to disorder and instability. People in a democracy, Plato asserts, are often motivated by their appetites and passions rather than reason and wisdom. This leads to poor decision-making and, ultimately, the descent of democracy into tyranny, as demagogues exploit the ignorance of the masses to gain power.

Key concern: Democracy allows unqualified individuals to rule, leading to chaos and the eventual rise of tyranny.
Alternative: Philosopher-kings—individuals who are trained in philosophy and reason—should rule because they are best equipped to make wise decisions.

2. Aristotle
Aristotle, while more measured than his teacher Plato, was also critical of democracy, although he distinguished between different forms of it. In Politics, he describes democracy as a "deviant" form of government when it degenerates into rule by the poor majority at the expense of the common good. He feared that democracy, if unchecked, would devolve into demagoguery, where leaders pander to popular desires and the masses act for their own self-interest rather than for the collective well-being of society. Aristotle favored a balanced constitution that combined elements of democracy, oligarchy, and aristocracy to avoid extremes.
Aristotle's classification



who rules?
good form
bad form




one person
monarchy
tyranny


few people
aristocracy
oligarchy


many people
polity / timocracy
democracy



Note the column under which democracy appears

Key concern: Democracy can lead to mob rule and short-sighted policies, with the poor majority dominating decision-making at the expense of the wealthy and more knowledgeable.
Alternative: A mixed government, incorporating the best elements of democracy and oligarchy to achieve stability and justice.

3. Henry David Thoreau
Thoreau’s criticism of democracy is less a philosophical condemnation and more a moral one. In his essay Civil Disobedience, Thoreau is critical of the way democracy functions in practice, particularly how it permits the majority to impose unjust policies, such as slavery and the Mexican-American War, which he strongly opposed. He argues that individuals have a duty to follow their conscience rather than conforming to unjust laws or majority decisions. For Thoreau, the moral weakness of democracy is that it enables the majority to enforce policies that violate individual rights and justice. His criticism is deeply rooted in his transcendentalist belief in individual conscience and higher moral law.

Key concern: Democracy can lead to the moral abdication of individuals, allowing unjust laws and policies to prevail simply because they have majority support.
Alternative: Individual moral integrity and civil disobedience as a means to resist unjust government actions.

4. Thomas Hobbes
Hobbes was a political philosopher who argued in Leviathan that without a strong, centralized authority, society would descend into chaos and the "state of nature." He believed that people are naturally self-interested and require governance to maintain order and prevent civil war.

Key Concern: Democracy leads to instability and chaos due to the lack of a centralized authority.
Alternative: Hobbes favored a monarchy as the most stable system to preserve order.

5. Friedrich Nietzsche
Nietzsche criticized democracy for promoting mediocrity and conformity, arguing that it suppresses individual greatness, creativity, and the "will to power." He viewed democracy as encouraging a "herd mentality" that stifles exceptional individuals.

Key Concern: Democracy erodes individual excellence and creativity by favoring equality over greatness.
Alternative: Nietzsche preferred an aristocratic model that values strong, exceptional individuals over the masses.

6. Alexis de Tocqueville
Tocqueville, in Democracy in America, admired aspects of democracy but warned about the "tyranny of the majority," where the majority's will could suppress individual freedoms and minority rights. He feared that democracy could lead to excessive equality, which stifles individual excellence.

Key Concern: Democracy risks suppressing individual freedom and diversity by prioritizing majority rule.
Alternative: Tocqueville supported a balanced form of democracy with checks to prevent majority tyranny.

7. James Madison
As a Founding Father, Madison expressed concerns in Federalist No. 10 about pure democracy, warning of the dangers of factions and mob rule. He believed that a large republic with representative government was necessary to protect individual rights and avoid tyranny.

Key Concern: Pure democracy allows factions to dominate, threatening individual rights and social stability.
Alternative: Madison advocated for a republic with representative government to safeguard against tyranny.

8. John Stuart Mill
Mill, though supportive of democracy, had reservations about its potential to limit individual freedom. In On Liberty, he warned of the "tyranny of the majority," where democratic decisions could stifle intellectual diversity.

Key Concern: Democracy can suppress individual freedoms and limit intellectual diversity through majority rule.
Alternative: Mill supported safeguards like plural voting to protect against the unwise decisions of the masses.

9. Joseph Schumpeter
Schumpeter, in Capitalism, Socialism, and Democracy, critiqued the ideal of democracy, arguing that it is more about elite competition for power than genuine public participation. He viewed democracy as a contest among elites rather than a true reflection of the people's will.

Key Concern: Democracy is less about public will and more about elite competition, undermining true democratic participation.
Alternative: Schumpeter favored a more pragmatic, elitist view of democracy focused on leadership competition.

10. Jean-Jacques Rousseau
Rousseau criticized the representative democracy of his time, arguing that it alienated people from their government. In The Social Contract, he advocated for direct democracy, where the general will of the people is expressed directly, though he acknowledged this was rare and difficult to achieve.

Key Concern: Representative democracy alienates people from the decision-making process.
Alternative: Rousseau advocated for direct democracy, where citizens express the general will directly.

Current Issues with Democracies
1. Populism

Definition: Populism involves political leaders appealing to the desires and prejudices of ordinary people, often at the expense of established political norms and institutions.

Impact: Populist leaders can undermine democratic institutions by eroding checks and balances, weakening the judiciary, and attacking the media. This can lead to authoritarianism masked as democracy.

Reference: Mudde, Cas, and Kaltwasser, Cristóbal Rovira. Populism: A Very Short Introduction. Oxford University Press, 2017.

Summary: This book offers a concise overview of populism, exploring its causes, manifestations, and impact on modern democracies.


2. Low Voter Turnout

Definition: Low voter turnout refers to a significant portion of the electorate choosing not to participate in elections.
Impact: This can undermine the legitimacy of elected governments and lead to policies that do not reflect the will of the majority. It often results from voter apathy, disenfranchisement, or dissatisfaction with the choices available.
Reference: Lijphart, Arend. "Unequal Participation: Democracy's Unresolved Dilemma." American Political Science Review, vol. 91, no. 1, 1997, pp. 1-14.
Summary: Lijphart discusses the issue of unequal voter turnout and its implications for democratic legitimacy.

3. Two-Party System Issues

Definition: In two-party systems, power is primarily shared between two major political parties, often leading to polarization.
Impact: This can result in gridlock, where little legislation is passed, and can discourage nuanced debate. It can also alienate voters who feel neither party represents their views, leading to voter apathy.
Reference: Rae, Douglas W. The Political Consequences of Electoral Laws. Yale University Press, 1967.
Summary: This book analyzes how different electoral systems, including two-party systems, impact political representation and party dynamics.

4. Multi-Party System Issues

Definition: In multi-party systems, multiple political parties have significant power and influence, often requiring coalition governments.
Impact: While this can lead to more diverse representation, it can also result in unstable governments, with frequent elections and difficulties in forming cohesive policies. Coalition governments can be fragile, leading to inefficiency.

Reference: Lijphart, Arend. Patterns of Democracy: Government Forms and Performance in Thirty-Six Countries. Yale University Press, 2012.


Summary: Lijphart examines the advantages and disadvantages of different democratic systems, including multi-party systems.

5. Polarization

Definition: Political polarization occurs when political parties, and their supporters, move towards extreme positions, leaving little room for compromise.
Impact: This can result in a fragmented society, where cooperation and dialogue between opposing groups become difficult, leading to legislative gridlock and social tensions.
Reference: McCarty, Nolan, Poole, Keith T., and Rosenthal, Howard. Polarized America: The Dance of Ideology and Unequal Riches. MIT Press, 2016.
Summary: This book discusses the causes and consequences of political polarization in the United States.

6. Disinformation and Fake News

Definition: The spread of false or misleading information to influence public opinion or discredit opponents.
Impact: Disinformation can erode trust in democratic institutions, create confusion among voters, and lead to poorly informed decision-making. It undermines the foundation of democracy, which relies on an informed electorate.
Reference: Wardle, Claire, and Derakhshan, Hossein. "Information Disorder: Toward an Interdisciplinary Framework for Research and Policy Making." Council of Europe Report, 2017.
Summary: This report explores the rise of disinformation, its impact on democracy, and potential policy responses.

7. Money in Politics

Definition: The influence of wealthy individuals, corporations, and special interest groups on political campaigns and policy-making.
Impact: This can lead to corruption, where policies favor the wealthy and powerful rather than the broader population. It also creates a perception (and often a reality) of unequal access to political power.
Reference: Lessig, Lawrence. Republic, Lost: How Money Corrupts Congress—and a Plan to Stop It. Twelve, 2011.
Summary: Lessig argues that the influence of money in politics is undermining American democracy and proposes solutions to address this issue.

8. Erosion of Civil Liberties

Definition: The gradual weakening or undermining of individual rights and freedoms, often justified by security or public order concerns.
Impact: This can lead to an authoritarian state, where dissent is punished, and the public is less able to hold leaders accountable. It often results in the suppression of free speech, freedom of assembly, and privacy.
Reference: Cole, David. Enemy Aliens: Double Standards and Constitutional Freedoms in the War on Terrorism. The New Press, 2003.
Summary: Cole examines how civil liberties have been eroded in the name of security, particularly in the context of the War on Terror.

9. Gerrymandering

Definition: The manipulation of electoral district boundaries to favor a particular political party.
Impact: Gerrymandering can entrench power, distort representation, and reduce electoral competition. It can lead to "safe" seats where one party has an overwhelming advantage, making elections less competitive and reducing voter engagement.
Reference: McGann, Anthony J., et al. Gerrymandering in America: The House of Representatives, the Supreme Court, and the Future of Popular Sovereignty. Cambridge University Press, 2016.
Summary: This book provides an in-depth analysis of gerrymandering and its effects on American democracy.

10. Judicial Overreach

Definition: When courts extend their influence into areas typically managed by the legislative or executive branches.
Impact: While courts are meant to uphold the constitution and protect rights, judicial overreach can lead to accusations of "legislating from the bench," potentially undermining democratic processes and causing tension between branches of government.
Reference: Waldron, Jeremy. Political Political Theory: Essays on Institutions. Harvard University Press, 2016.
Summary: Waldron critiques judicial overreach and argues for the importance of democratic deliberation in resolving political disputes.

11. Electoral Fraud and Manipulation

Definition: Actions taken to illegally influence the outcome of an election.
Impact: Electoral fraud can undermine the integrity of elections, leading to illegitimate governments. It erodes trust in the democratic process and can incite political instability.
Reference: Lehoucq, Fabrice. Electoral Fraud: Causes, Types, and Consequences. Annual Review of Political Science, 2003.
Summary: This article examines the causes and consequences of electoral fraud in various democracies.

12. Voter Suppression

Definition: Efforts to prevent or discourage certain groups of people from voting.
Impact: Voter suppression tactics, such as strict ID laws, purging voter rolls, or reducing polling places, can disproportionately affect marginalized communities, undermining the principle of equal representation.
Reference: Anderson, Carol. One Person, No Vote: How Voter Suppression Is Destroying Our Democracy. Bloomsbury Publishing, 2018.
Summary: Anderson discusses the history and modern forms of voter suppression in the United States.

13. Media Bias and Concentration

Definition: The concentration of media ownership in a few hands and the resulting bias in news coverage.
Impact: Media concentration can limit the diversity of viewpoints presented to the public, leading to a less informed electorate and skewed public perceptions. Bias in media can also reinforce polarization.
Reference: McChesney, Robert W. Rich Media, Poor Democracy: Communication Politics in Dubious Times. New Press, 2000.
Summary: McChesney explores the impact of media concentration on democracy and the resulting bias in news coverage.

14. Globalization and Its Discontents

Definition: The impact of global economic forces on national sovereignty and local economies.
Impact: Globalization can lead to job losses in certain sectors, increase inequality, and fuel nationalist and populist sentiments. It can also challenge the ability of democracies to regulate their economies independently.
Reference: Stiglitz, Joseph E. Globalization and Its Discontents. W.W. Norton & Company, 2002.
Summary: Stiglitz critiques the negative effects of globalization on developing countries and democratic governance.

15. Technological Disruption

Definition: The impact of rapidly advancing technology on society and the economy.
Impact: Technology, while offering many benefits, can also lead to job displacement, surveillance, and challenges to privacy. It can widen the gap between those with access to technology and those without, creating new forms of inequality.
Reference: Zuboff, Shoshana. The Age of Surveillance Capitalism: The Fight for a Human Future at the New Frontier of Power. PublicAffairs, 2019.
Summary: Zuboff examines how technology, particularly data collection, is disrupting democracy and privacy.

17. Policy Inconsistency
also called policy discontinuity or shortermism in democracies. This occurs when a government makes decisions or implements policies that are then reversed, altered, or dealt with by subsequent governments, especially after an electoral defeat. The consequences of such decisions can be significant, leading to instability, economic uncertainty, and a lack of long-term planning.
Key Aspects of Policy Inconsistency:

Short-Termism: Governments may take short-sighted or populist decisions to win votes, knowing they might not be in power long enough to face the negative consequences.

Electoral Cycles: The frequent change of leadership due to elections can result in policies being reversed or dramatically altered, making it difficult to implement long-term strategies.

Economic Impact: Rash decisions, such as sudden economic reforms, can have long-lasting impacts that subsequent governments must manage, often at the cost of their own agendas.

Credibility and Trust: This inconsistency can undermine public and international confidence in a country's governance, affecting everything from foreign investment to domestic stability.


An example of this might be seen in the frequent changes in tax policy or environmental regulations, where one government might implement strict rules, only for the next to loosen them, creating a lack of consistency that can be damaging to both businesses and the environment.
Basically the situation that in democratic systems, electoral considerations often lead to a focus on short-term gains rather than long-term planning and stability.
The most extreme current example is regarding Shorttermism is climate change
Current Thinkers

Jeff Sachs
Correlation between internal democracy and external violence
John Mearsheimer
The world is defined by Great Power Politics is inherently tragic


Pretty much the evening news of the USA. At least we have something to criticize, and can criticize it. It's a start.

"May you live in interesting times"... "May you come to the attention of those in authority"... "May the gods give you everything you ask for" (Terry Pratchett).

@ScottRowe Well yes n no. . Some of these are so American we non Americans hardly know the name eg. gerrymandering. Others are more western european others are universal and perennial. And no you cannot question foundational mythologies

"What if this is as good as it gets?"

@ScottRowe Not sure if this is the right idiom... Hail Mary!!

@ScottRowe The reflection on anicca — viz. All conditioned existence, without exception, is "transient, evanescent, inconstant is said to bring peace

I think many people head in that direction as their lives progress, but people who want power do not. What happened to your point #16?

To improve democracy you must engage and educate the participants of the democratic state in question. The biggest challenge of any society larger than what humans have a natural capacity to manage, is how to keep the participants engaged in the well-being and functionality of the society they partake in. To improve that, the society would have to agree on fundamental principles.
You could say that they already have, in that they agreed on certain principles when the society was founded. I would counter and say the current society of any democracy that has existed for longer than a 100 years is a shadow of its original principles, as the state of the society at the moment of founding is no longer comparable.
So, democracy requires a foundational structure that facilitates an affirmation of their basic principles, a system and a people that accept that whatever structure they arrive at, would necessarily have to adapt in accordance with the environment. This should probably be the role of education that includes subjects that deal honestly with our issues, and that encourages errors and faults in exploring these issues so that we encourage dialectical discussions. We also have to deal with shame, as it encourages faulty information or reserved information, and gives rise to dishonesty.
If the system causes society to devolve into polar opinions expressed through debates and media, the voter can not gain enough information to make a rational choice, and so I feel it doesn't qualify as a democracy.
Edit: Spelling errors and clarification.

I paraphrase Churchill, but this version communicates his fundamental meaning. Democracy is flawed. So how can we improve it to achieve a more perfect republic? We would have to agree some ground rules. These have to be rational and objective. So the political system cannot be based on irrational beliefs. No theocracies, no racial hierarchies, no class systems. Since we need to start somewhere with positive properties, I am going to propose efficiency. So which is more efficient - equality or inequality? Inequality seems to lead to all sorts of inefficiency. So I propose that an efficient political system promotes equality of opportunity. My next proposal is wellbeing, of the individual and society. Since inequality damages wellbeing, but excessive state control also damages wellbeing, developing inequality would have to be controlled at a fair level. In effect, there would be a progressive tax system on income and wealth. Citizens would be guaranteed a basic income. Next, state interference would be minimised. The system would be a liberal, secular democracy with a capitalist economy working synergistically with an interventionist state. There seem to elements of these ideas in some current political systems. However, the tolerance of inefficiency and inequality by some powerful groups or even one powerful individual tends to cause damage.

Please give references & relate your points to esrablished philosophical work. You say "No theocracies, no racial hierarchies, no class systems", but not why you are against that. Is it even possible to eliminate class systems? Is inequality always inefficient? Conservatives might argue 'striving' is good, & drives economies.

I don't know about the how good/bad democracy (relatively/absolutely), but what we practice as democracy today is to my reckoning obsolete. With a cell phone in every citizen's hands and the worldwide internet, referendums are totally feasible. No need for all this election "nonsense". Would you consider this improvement?

The last big world-news referendum — Brexit — do you consider it a success? People are stupider evern towards their own self-interest than we appreciate

@Rushi then Churchill was right!

Representative democracies are a gigantic improvement on direct democracy, like referendums. Citizen Assemblies are a much better candidate than referendums.

What about an anarchosyndiclysm.?

@CriglCragl, why then Brexit?

@8Mad0Manc8. what's that?

@Hudjefa: Brexit being the point, immigration wasn't reduced, UK trade is still overwhelmingly subject to EU law now with no UK say over it, EU investment in places like Cornwall & Wales that voted Brexit will not be replaced, almost no trade deals done, & the economy is so damaged Conservatives had their worst defeat since WW2. All not only predicted but predictable. Brexit was based on lies pitched to an electorate too ill-informed to recognise them.

@CriglCragl that's sad to hear. If the situation is bad, I hope it improves. Regarding representative democracy, it's got a good track record.

@Hudjefa: Representative democracy does, sure, parliamentarians, senates, etc. Was just hearing about the tech-enabled version of direct democracy in Taiwan, see eg 'Can Taiwan Provide the Alternative to Digital Authoritarianism?' https://thediplomat.com/2021/07/can-taiwan-provide-the-alternative-to-digital-authoritarianism/

@CriglCragl,  Taiwan huh? Amazing.


Your question starts with a presupposition: “if democracy is the
least worst … “.
Hence to agree with or to object to this presupposition already
requires a measure how to assess any form of political government.

But the problem is: The history of European philosophy from Plato’s
Republic and Aristotle’s Politics onward does not agree about such a
measure. And if you ask the oldest state in Europe, the Vatican
State, you get again quite a different answer.
These historical
facts show: Which form of government meets best our expectations is
not a question which has been decided on the field of philosophy.
Nevertheless political philosophy helps to elaborate arguments and principles
to provide a rational basis for the political discussion.

A good start to inform about political philosophy is - like often -
https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/ancient-political/



But philosophers like Rousseau & Locke had profound real-world impacts. The point is that moving forward involves imagining new things, & that is the question here. Can we?
